# Store variable in XSL

Tags: php, xml, xslt, variables, store

Iam writing a program to call php from xsl but I need to store an xsl variable so i can send it to php function php:functionString()

```
<xsl:template match="atom:entry">

 <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 10">
   <table border="0" width="55"  cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4" style="float:left;">
      <tr >
         <td width="55">

    <a href="?page_id=9#anchor-{ atom:id }" >
    <img id="icon">
<xsl:attribute name="src">

<xsl:value-of select="./im:image[1]"/>

</xsl:attribute>
</img></a>
</td>
</tr>

         <tr> <td width="35" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; color:black; font-weight:bold;">
             <xsl:value-of select="atom:category/@label"/> </td></tr>
          <tr> <td width="35" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; color:black;">   <xsl:value-of select="./im:price"/>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr> <td>Rating: <xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('PD::parseData','$id')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: If the function `php:functionString()` is expecting its second argument to be a string, double or boolean, and `$id`(which you forgot to show to us!)  contains such a value, then most likely the parameter will be passed OK. You need to test what type in PHP should be used for document-node, node, attribute or a node-set.

Comment: $id is just an example. I just need the correct syntax in place of $id and it is to be the value of atom:id, i just don't know how to store id and pass it on to php:functionString()

Comment: Nitin Pant: Use: `<xsl:variable name="id" select="atom:id"/>` . Then pass it to the function exactly as you do in your code example. Alternatively, try:  `<xsl:variable name="id" select="string(atom:id)"/>`

Comment: Nitin Pant: You need to read a good book on XSLT: http://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/36305

Comment: @dimitre whether i use `php:functionString('PD::parseData','{$id}')` OR `php:functionString('PD::parseData','{$id}')` , its only passing string(and not the value!) {$id} or $id correspondingly.. pls help. I am trying to style itunes iOS app RSS feed and using the book "XSLT Mastering XML Transformations" by O'reilly

Comment: Nitin Pant: The second argument should just be: `$id` -- no quotes or curly brackets around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('PD::parseData','$id')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

**Use**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('PD::parseData', $id)"/>
```

**The former passes as parameter the *string* `"$id"` not the variable `$id`.**